# How to create bass tabs based of guitar tabs

Tags: guitar, chords, bass-guitar

I have been learning Drawing Board by George Ezra on my Guitar. My friend plays bass but we can't find any tabs, so I was wondering if there is a way to match guitar chords with bass notes?

Its a pretty easy song and only has 4 chords in total. I know the song doesn't have a bass but just wanted to play for a bit of fun.

Does anyone know the sort of notes you'd play on a bass to accompany say a guitar with a capo on the 3rd fret playing D, Em, G? Or even better if someone clever could bass tab the song!

Cheers ALL :)
https://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/tab/george-ezra/drawing-board-chords-1506315

Answer (score 3):

With the capo on the 3rd fret the song becomes a minor 3rd higher (3 semitones up).  So the D chord sounds as an F, Em sounds as Gm, etc.  The bass player would base the notes around the key of F major.  Fiddle around with what sounds right, but these notes should be safe enough on the bass - F and C (D shape on guitar), G and D (Em shape on guitar), C and G (A shape on guitar) and Bb and F (G shape on guitar).  Of course you can become more adventurous with passing notes, and arpeggios, etc.

Answer (score 1):

On  this Tab crawler site you can find out which notes the bass root tones are:

https://www.tabcrawler.com/3581953/george-ezra/drawing-board

The setting is in C, the key of D transposes your song 2 semitones and the capo in fret 3 another whole and a halftone: All in all a 4th up:

Thats why you take the given chords and click on the **setting F** on the tuning settings in the first row on the top and the sheet will show the chords that are actually played. Now your comrade has to know of course where this notes sit (on which fret of his bass guitar. That’s probably another question for a beginner, but the problem is easy to be solved.

Learning to read bass clef is also useful. Then this sheet music will give an idea what the bass is playing:

https://www.sheetmusicdeluxe.com/product/drawing-board-george-ezra/